# Trouble with making a Time Series Bar Chart with Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been working to make a time series bar chart plot of two organisms collected monthly in ggplot2. When I run the code I end up getting a chart without any selected Y values. Is there an issue with the way I am gathering data? Should I use tidyr? The code is below. Thank you

```
library(ggplot2)
myDF <-
data.frame(Month = as.Date(c('2018-07-15','2018-08-08','2019-01-05','2019-02-27', '2019-03-17', '2019-04-21', '2019-05-08', '2019-06-07', '2019-07-29', '2019-08-18', '2019-09-27', '2019-10-27', '2019-11-08')), C.w.= c(19.44, 21.4, 4.5, 0.29, 30.9, 22.95, 5.4, 5.67, 0.2, 0.07, 0, 2.06, 0.39), O.m. = c(0, 0, 27, 14, 13.95, 7, 2.53, 8.96, 3.4, 10.43, 15.76, 5.96, 18.18)) 
ggplot(data = myDF, aes(x = 'Month', y = 'Density per 10 cm Octocoral', fill = 'Species')) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of errors in the way you are trying to plot your data.

If I have to guess, I would say that you forget to tell us that each columns represent a different species, but you are filling by species without having a column `Species` in your dataframe, so `gglot2` can't guess what you are talking about.

So, if I'm right and each column correspond to a different species, you need first to reshape your dataframe into a longer format, here I used `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` package.

So, having `y = 'Density per 10 cm Octocoral'` is also wrong because I presumed it is the title you want to put as y axis. Again, there is no columns refereed by this name, so `ggplot2` can't make the graph. If it is the title for y axis you ant to label, you have to use `labs(y = ...)` or `ylab(...)`

Finally, you don't need brackets for assigning Month to x axis. Because you assign the dataframe to be used, you can directly write the name of the column to be used as x axis. Take a look of my code below.

```r
DF <- myDF %>% pivot_longer(-Month, names_to = "Species", values_to = "values")
DF

# A tibble: 26 x 3
   Month      Species values
   <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
 1 2018-07-15 C.w.    19.4  
 2 2018-07-15 O.m.     0    
 3 2018-08-08 C.w.    21.4  
 4 2018-08-08 O.m.     0    
 5 2019-01-05 C.w.     4.5  
 6 2019-01-05 O.m.    27    
 7 2019-02-27 C.w.     0.290
 8 2019-02-27 O.m.    14    
 9 2019-03-17 C.w.    30.9  
10 2019-03-17 O.m.    14.0  
# … with 16 more rows
```

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF,aes(x = Month, y = values, fill = Species))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  labs(y = "Density per 10 cm Octocoral")
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to achieve ?

---

To my opinion, as you have big gaps in your date sequence, I don't think a barchart is really appropriate. I would rather suggest to use `geom_line` such as:

```r
  ggplot(DF,aes(x = Month, y = values, color = Species))+
    geom_line()+
    geom_point()+
    labs(y = "Density per 10 cm Octocoral")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for that concise answer! I also agree that the line plot looks better as well. I am still struggling to reshape my data specifically from a csv file containing my data. Any suggestions? Would you need the file in order to see how it is organized? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think it is a different question. You first need to load your file into R and see how it looks like (you can use `read.csv` or `read.table` to load it). Then, you can apply `pivot_longer` on columns you are looking to reshape: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html